# mi calendario se repite al darle prev o next

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo un calendario en jQuery. ¿Como le podría hacer para que no se repita el tbody. Aun no tengo las condiciones para los años pero es lo de menos. Ante mano gracias.

```js
      $(function(){

        var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();


        function days(month,year) {
          //last day of month
          var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

          //first day of month
          var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

          //month string
          $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

          var counter = 0;
          $("#days").append("<tr>");
            for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

              //blank space
              if(i == 1){
                for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
                  $("#days").append("<td></td>");
                }
              }

              //new week
              if(counter%7 == 0){
                $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
              }

              //display days
              $("#days").append("<td><a href='?d="+i+"&m="+month+"&y="+year+"'>"+i+"</a></td>");
            }

        };

        days(month,year);

        //left click
        $("#prev").on("click",function(){
          month--;
          days(month,year);
        });

        //right click
        $("#next").on("click",function(){
          month++;
          days(month,year);
        });

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</td>
        <td id="date" colspan="5"></td>
        <td class="btn" id="next">&rang;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SUN</td>
        <td>MON</td>
        <td>TUE</td>
        <td>WEN</td>
        <td>THU</td>
        <td>FRI</td>
        <td>SAT</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="days"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un pequeño error en **append** en los **dias** solo debias cambiarlo a **html** Te recomiendo leer un poco de documentacion para que puedas saber en donde aplicarlo cada uno de estos.

[AQUI UN REFERENCIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append)

```js
    $(function(){

        var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();


        function days(month,year) {
          //last day of month
          var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

          //first day of month
          var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

          //month string
          $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

          var counter = 0;
          $("#days").html("<tr>");
            for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

              //blank space
              if(i == 1){
                for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
                  $("#days").append("<td></td>");
                }
              }

              //new week
              if(counter%7 == 0){
                $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
              }

              //display days
              $("#days").append("<td><a href='?d="+i+"&m="+month+"&y="+year+"'>"+i+"</a></td>");
            }

        };

        days(month,year);

        //left click
        $("#prev").on("click",function(){
          month--;
          days(month,year);
        });

        //right click
        $("#next").on("click",function(){
          month++;
          days(month,year);
        });

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</td>
        <td id="date" colspan="5"></td>
        <td class="btn" id="next">&rang;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SUN</td>
        <td>MON</td>
        <td>TUE</td>
        <td>WEN</td>
        <td>THU</td>
        <td>FRI</td>
        <td>SAT</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="days"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la referencia